# Dynamically adding Context Menu items

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

For some reason, regardless of how many times the toolstripmenuitem is added to the context menu, it always says the context menu does not contain the item.

```
ToolStripMenuItem Colour = new ToolStripMenuItem("Colour");

ctmFile.Show(Cursor.Position);
Selecteditem = lvFiles.FocusedItem.Text.ToString();
if (lvFiles.FocusedItem.ImageKey.ToString() == "Folder")
{

    if (ctmFile.Items.Contains(Colour) == false)
    {
        ctmFile.Items.Add(Colour);
    }

}
else
{
    if(ctmFile.Items.Contains(Colour))
    {
        ctmFile.Items.Remove(Colour);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it fixed. I'm an idiot.

Comment: If the answer below helped you fix it, mark it as the chosen answer. If you found your own solution could you post your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add on top of Ed's answer, I would recommend using keys instead:

```
ctmFile.Show(Cursor.Position);
Selecteditem = lvFiles.FocusedItem.Text.ToString();
if (lvFiles.FocusedItem.ImageKey.ToString() == "Folder")
{

    if (!ctmFile.Items.ContainsKey("Colour")) 
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem Colour = new ToolStripMenuItem("Colour");
        Colour.Name= "Colour"; //Add a name (key) to your menu.
        ctmFile.Items.Add(Colour);
    }

}
else
{
    if (ctmFile.Items.ContainsKey("Colour")) 
    {
        ctmFile.Items.RemoveByKey("Colour");
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this better than mine because it finds the menu item using a framework-appropriate feature.

Comment: Thank you, @EdPlunkett. You solved the problem though :-) (new instance every time).

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new menu item and searching for that. But since it was just created, it obviously can't already be in the menu. That's why you never find it there. A *different* menu item with that text may have been added before, but your code is not looking for that one.

You need to search the menu items for an item that has that text. The code can be simplified a bit in other ways:

```
var colorItemText = "Colour";
var colorMenuItem = ctmFile.Items.Cast<ToolStripMenuItem>()
                      .FirstOrDefault(mi => mi.Text == colorItemText);

if (lvFiles.FocusedItem.ImageKey.ToString() == "Folder")
{
    //  Create and add if not already present
    if (colorMenuItem == null)
    {
        colorMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(colorItemText);
        ctmFile.Items.Add(colorMenuItem);
    }
}
else if (colorMenuItem != null)
{
    //  Remove if already present. 
    ctmFile.Items.Remove(colorMenuItem);
}
```